# Navigation with only Odometry( without Lidar )

Tags: navigation, odometry, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I want to compare the performance of Odom and Lidar. I managed to examine the accuracy of the lidar while the Turtelbot3 is not moving. Now I'm trying to investigate how accurate the odom is without interference from lidar, I'd be so grateful for any suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397626/navigation-with-only-odometry(-without-lidar-)/) by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2022-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Belghiti. From what I understood, you want to use the Navigation Stack (probably *move_base*) based only on odometry. Considering that, the Navigation Stack requires a transformation from **odom** to **map** frame. Therefore, you need to publish a constant transformation between these two frames. You can write a node to do that, but I think that [static_transform_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/tf#static_transform_publisher) does exactly what you need. You can just set zero to all offset coordinates.

I hope this will help you.

---

Originally posted by [schulze18](https://answers.ros.org/users/51840/schulze18/) with karma: 91 on 2022-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Belghiti](https://answers.ros.org/users/99615/belghiti/) on 2022-03-20**:
Hi again,
thank u so much sir for ur time and help, ur suggestion seems like a good way to solve my problem (especially if u mean that the lidar won't interfere in any way possible), and i hope i can put it to use cause im still so new to all of this.
Thanks again!

**Comment by [schulze18](https://answers.ros.org/users/51840/schulze18/) on 2022-03-20**:
You're welcome. In this case, you can even turn off your Lidar.